# XSLT dynamically creating rows and columns

Tags: xslt

I have an XML file with following format:

```
 <DataSet>
  <Data id ="1" columns ="4">
    <item name ="data1" value="value1"/>
    <item name ="data2" value="value2"/>
    <item name ="data3" value="value3"/>
    <item name ="data4" value="value4"/>
    <item name ="data5" value="value5"/>
  </Data>
  <Data id="2" columns ="2">
    <item name ="data1" value="value1"/>
    <item name ="data2" value="value2"/>
    <item name ="data3" value="value3"/>
    <item name ="data4" value="value4"/>
  </Data>
</DataSet>
```

and I need an XSL transformation to get following table structure. Here the idea is to display the name and value attributes in two adjacent cells. So an 'item' will be associated with 2 columns and a row will be holding name/value pairs of two items. The number of columns will be specified in the Data element and will be always multiples of 2.

```
<report>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>value1</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>value2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>value3</td>
      <td>data4</td>
      <td>value4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data5</td>
      <td>value5</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
 <table>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>value1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>value2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>value3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data4</td>
      <td>value4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</report>
```

Comment: Looks easy enough, have you delved into XSLT at all? Any progress? Anything at all to show?

Comment: I am pretty new to XSLT, so just reading through some documentations to understand it.

Comment: Just noticed that the xml has really inconsistent formatting with variable spacing between an attribute name and the value such as in `id="` and `id ="`. While not technically incorrect, it is very odd.

Comment: The XML provided here is hand coded to provide just the structure of the input file.

Comment: You may be interested in a simpler solution, which is actually correct (it correctly gives the empty cells). Please see my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following XSL transformation applied to the provided input produces the desired output. Some explanation is provided below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/DataSet"><report>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </report></xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Data">
        <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(item)" />
        <xsl:variable name="M" select="@columns div 2" />
        <xsl:variable name="N" select="($count + ($count mod $M)) div $M" />
        <table>
            <xsl:call-template name="nth-row">
                <xsl:with-param name="n" select="1" />
                <xsl:with-param name="M" select="$M" />
                <xsl:with-param name="N" select="$N" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="nth-row">
        <xsl:param name="n" />
        <xsl:param name="N" />
        <xsl:param name="M" />
        <tr>
            <xsl:call-template name="nmth-cell">
                <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n" />
                <xsl:with-param name="m" select="1" />
                <xsl:with-param name="N" select="$N" />
                <xsl:with-param name="M" select="$M" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </tr>
        <xsl:if test="$N > $n">
            <xsl:call-template name="nth-row">
                <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n + 1" />
                <xsl:with-param name="N" select="$N" />
                <xsl:with-param name="M" select="$M" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="nmth-cell">
        <xsl:param name="n" />
        <xsl:param name="m" />
        <xsl:param name="N" />
        <xsl:param name="M" />
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="($n - 1) * $M + $m" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="item[position()=$pos]">
                <td><xsl:value-of select="item[position()=$pos]/@name" /></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="item[position()=$pos]/@value" /></td>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:if test="$M > $m">
            <xsl:call-template name="nmth-cell">
                <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n" />
                <xsl:with-param name="m" select="$m + 1" />
                <xsl:with-param name="N" select="$N" />
                <xsl:with-param name="M" select="$M" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

1. Matching `/DataSet` produces the root element `<report />` and continues applying templates.
2. Matching `Data` from inside `/DataSet` produces a `<table />` for each `<Data />` element and then starts the interesting part by calling the template named `nth-row`. The variables and parameters used are:

   - **n**: number of current row, starting at 1
   - **M**: number of columns, calculated from the attribute `@columns` divided by two, because each `<item />` results in two `<td />` elements.
   - **N**: number of rows, calculated from the number of `<item />` elements present and divided by **M**. To account for `div` truncating integer values the remainder `$count mod $M` is added to `$count` before.
3. Now there come some recursive template calls. Each time `nth-row` is called, it outputs a `<tr />` and then calls `nmth-cell` with appropriate parameters. As long as the current row is not the last one, `nth-row` is recursively called with an incremented value of `$n`.
4. Finally the template `nmth-cell` each time it is called outputs two `<td />` elements containing the values from the appropriate `<item />` or nothing, if there is no corresponding `<item />`. As long as the current column is not the last one, `nmth-cell` is recursively called with an incremented value of `$m`.

I hope this helps. Feel free to ask, if there is anything wrong with this or unclear to you.

Comment: Yes, it works great! Thanks for the quick solution. Yes need to have empty cell if data not available.

Comment: @hielsnoppe I believe I will need your expertise in my case :). I am trying to display two content per row in my collection using XSL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26848912/how-to-set-overflow-content-to-go-underneath-instead-of-fitting-in-one-row/26849124?noredirect=1#comment42261215_26849124

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much simpler solution.

**This XSLT 1.0 style-sheet...**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <report>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </report>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Data">
  <xsl:variable name="cols" select="@columns" />
  <table>
    <xsl:for-each select="item[position()*2 mod $cols = (2 mod $cols)]">
      <tr>
       <xsl:for-each select="(.|following-sibling::item)
          [ position()*2 &lt;= $cols]">
         <td><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></td>  
         <td><xsl:value-of select="@value" /></td>  
       </xsl:for-each> 
       <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
         <xsl:for-each select="((/)//*)[position() &lt;=
              ($cols - (count(.|following-sibling::item)*2))]">
            <td />
         </xsl:for-each>   
       </xsl:if>  
      </tr>  
    </xsl:for-each>  
  </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...when applied to this input...**

```
<DataSet>
  <Data id ="1" columns ="4">
    <item name ="data1" value="value1"/>
    <item name ="data2" value="value2"/>
    <item name ="data3" value="value3"/>
    <item name ="data4" value="value4"/>
    <item name ="data5" value="value5"/>
  </Data>
  <Data id="2" columns ="2">
    <item name ="data1" value="value1"/>
    <item name ="data2" value="value2"/>
    <item name ="data3" value="value3"/>
    <item name ="data4" value="value4"/>
  </Data>
</DataSet>
```

**...yields...**

```
<report>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>value1</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>value2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>value3</td>
      <td>data4</td>
      <td>value4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data5</td>
      <td>value5</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>value1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>value2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>value3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data4</td>
      <td>value4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</report>
```

### Explanation

1. You can very simple use `position()` to structure the output into a matrix. This is far preferable to a convoluted call-template with many parameters.
2. Use the `html` output method instead of the default `xml` output method. This gives your html style of encoding for empty elements (like `<td></td>` over xml style `</td>`).
3. Use the [Piez Method](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/muench.html#d9945e300) to emit the odd empty table cells on the last row of the table.

Comment: I believe I will need your expertise in my case :). I am trying to display two content per row in my collection using XSL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26848912/how-to-set-overflow-content-to-go-underneath-instead-of-fitting-in-one-row/26849124?noredirect=1#comment42261215_26849124

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what formatting you want but this should get you close i hope. It makes a table per data set with the data and value pairs next to each other. Just comment if you need formatting help too

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <report>
      <xsl:for-each select="DataSet/Data">
      <table>
          <xsl:for-each select="item">
              <tr>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></td>
              </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
       </table>
       </xsl:for-each>
  </report>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I think this will be always creating a two column table. Here my problem is number of columns is dynamic based on the 'column' attribute specified in 'Data' element.

Comment: Yes, it does. I'm working on a solution that takes the `col` attribute into account.